# Choosing an area on the image for classification

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, classification

If anybody is familiar with classification in remote sensing
you know at first we should choose a region on the image and use information on this region to extract statistical parameters.
how can I choose this area of the image in matlab?

---

I think I found the answer to my own question.
As our friend user2466766 said I used roipoly to have a mask image and then I multiplied this mask with my image using '.*'.
then I extracted nonzero elements of the resulted matrix with the function nonzeros.
and know I have the digital numbers of the region within the polygon in a columnal matrix that can be used to calculate statistical parameters like variance, mean and etc

Answer (score 1):

Try roipoly. It allows you to create a mask image. If you are looking for more flexibility you can use poly2mask.

Comment: I don't want to have a mask. I mean I want to have the information (digital numbers) within the polygon

Comment: Is it a regular region, like a square? If it is you can crop the image and extract the information from that. Otherwise you can perform the calculations on the entire image and then limit your data to the region of the mask.

Comment: Can you explain alittle more about the case that the region is not a regular one?

Comment: What kind of statistical parameters are you extracting? The experience that I have is in SIFT descriptors. I have endoscopic images that where annotated. I extract the SIFT points of interest on the all image and then delete the ones that are outside of the mask. Here's how I did it:1.for j=length(frames):-1:1;2.if imask(frames(2,j),frames(1,j))==0 3.frames(1,j)=0; 4.frames(2,j)=0; 5.end 6.end 7.ind=find(frames(2,:)==0); 8.frames(:,ind)=[];